# Trying to check if a file exists in internal storage

Tags: java, android

The following code is how I am trying to identify if a file exists in the internal storage, `MODE_PRIVATE`.

```
public boolean isset(String filename){
    FileInputStream fos = null;
    try {
       fos = openFileInput(filename);
       //fos = openFileInput(getFilesDir()+"/"+filename);
       if (fos != null) {
         return true;
       }else{
         return false;
       }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    //File file=new File(mContext.getFilesDir(),filename);

    //boolean exists = fos.exists();
    }
```

However, it goes into the exception and doesn't continue with the code. It doesn't do the return. Why?

Comment: Can you provide us with the stack trace?

Answer (score 123):

hope this method helps you.

```java
public boolean fileExist(String fname){
    File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fname);
    return file.exists();
}
```

Comment: @bsara Why the base context instead of application's context, or both works?

Comment: You don't need any context - if you want to access the file from an activity or service, you can do it directly.

Answer (score 13):

For internal storage, this works for me:

```
public boolean isFilePresent(String fileName) {
    String path = getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
    File file = new File(path);
    return file.exists();
}
```

Comment: Day late and dollar short, but if you want to shorten this, `getAbsolutePath()` is not needed as `getFilesDir()` already returns the absoulte path.   Check Google's documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin: This works for me !!**

```
fun check(path: String?): Boolean
{
    val file = File(path)
    return file.exists()
}
```